# jbpm kieworkbench does not show icon for custom workitemdefinition

Tags: jboss, jbpm, business-process-management, workbench, kie

I'm using the KIE workbench in JBPM 6 (6.1) to set up a process. I also added a custom work item definition like this:

```
[
    "name" : "MyTask",
    "parameters" : [
        "Param1" : new StringDataType()
    ],
    "results" : [
        "Result" : new ObjectDataType(),
    ],
    "displayName" : "MyTask",
    "icon" : "myicon.png"
  ]
```

In addition I uploaded the corresponding file myicon.png. The icon is in the same folder as the wdi file, so the path should be correct.

Everythink works fine, except for the fact that the kie designer always shows the default icon instead of the icon I uploaded. I can also change it to a different default icon, but not to one I uploaded myself.

I can't find what is wrong. No errors are thrown in jboss log.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it seems that this is a known bug due to https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBPM-4407